# One to many Enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have this 2 enum that I need to relate PendingStatus to TransactionStatus

To explain, for each transaction there is one single status that I use TransactionStatus enum for, then for each TransactionStatus there is many pending reasons that I use PendingStatus enum for?

```
    /// <summary>
/// Represent all available status for Transaction
/// </summary>
public enum TransactionStatus
{
    New =0,
    Submitted =1,
    PendingStatus = 2,
    Accepted = 3,
    Rejected =4,
    InProgress =5,
    Completed=6,
    Failed=7,
    Canceled=8
}

/// <summary>
/// Represent all available pending status for Transaction
/// </summary>
public enum PendingStatus
{
    PendingA =0,
    PendingX =1,
    PendingY = 2,
}
```

How can I approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enum values as bitflag, as explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2004/04/07/109095.aspx).

This way you can mix PendingStatus and TransactionStatus together.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent all available status for Transaction
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum TransactionStatus
{
    New = 0,
    Submitted = 1,
    PendingStatus = 2,
    Accepted = 4,
    Rejected = 8,
    InProgress = 16,
    Completed = 32,
    Failed = 64,
    Canceled = 128
}

/// <summary>
/// Represent all available pending status for Transaction
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum PendingStatus
{
    PendingA = 256,
    PendingX = 512,
    PendingY = 1024
}  

// Example to set transaction as accepted and pending

var MyTransactionStatus = Accepted & PendingA;

// How to check transaction is pendingA regardless of its status ?

if (MyTransactionStatus & PendingA == PendingA) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the FlagsAttribute. So you could use a binary comparison.

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum TransactionStatus
{
    New = 0,
    Submitted = 1,
    PendingStatus = 2,
    Accepted = 4,
    // (...)
}

[FlagsAttribute]
public enum PendingStatus
{
    PendingA = 256,
    PendingX = 512,
    PendingY = 1024,
}
```